# Python Insert Matrix into another Matrix

Tags: python, list

What I want to do is to insert a matrix (of str) in an other matrix.

```
HM = 
[['', '', '', '', ''],
 ['', '', '', '', ''],
 ['', '', '', '', ''],
 ['', '', '', '', ''],
 ['', '', '', '', ''],
 ['', '', '', '', ''],
 ['', '', '', '', '']]
B = [["AA", "BB"],["CC","DD"]]
offset = (1,2)
```

The result should be:

```
[['', '', '', '', ''],
 ['', '', 'AA', 'BB', ''],
 ['', '', 'CC', 'DD', ''],
 ['', '', '', '', ''],
 ['', '', '', '', ''],
 ['', '', '', '', ''],
 ['', '', '', '', '']]
```

working on jupyter notebook version 3.7, tried np.insert, tried HM + B, tried np slash

```
HM = [[""]*15]*10
B = [["BBB"]*3, ["CCC"]*3, ["DDD"]*3]
offsetx = 2
offsety = 1
for x in range(1, 1 + offsetx):
    for y in range(2, 2 + offsety):
        HM[x][y] = B[x][y] 
HM
```

Comment: Like `HM.append(B)`?

Comment: What is the problem? Does the code works? What is the result?

Comment: My Problem is, that there are unexpected effects - only a single element is put into the matrix. Using np - only the first letter is put into the matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
HM = [['', '', '', '', ''], ['', '', '', '', ''], ['', '', '', '', ''], ['', '', '', '', ''], ['', '', '', '', ''], ['', '', '', '', ''], ['', '', '', '', '']]
B, offset = [["AA", "BB"],["CC","DD"]], (1, 2)
_b = iter(B)
new_data = [a[:offset[-1]]+(lambda x:x+a[len(x)+offset[-1]:])(next(_b)) if offset[0] <= i <= (offset[0]+len(offset)-1) else a 
    for i, a in enumerate(HM)]
```

Output:

```
[['', '', '', '', ''], 
 ['', '', 'AA', 'BB', ''], 
 ['', '', 'CC', 'DD', ''], 
 ['', '', '', '', ''], 
 ['', '', '', '', ''], 
 ['', '', '', '', ''], 
 ['', '', '', '', '']]
```

Comment: @Erich Glad to help!

Comment: could you please try to use a 3x3 matrix as B  to insert  and let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing element by element with index in a double for loop.

Given the matrix:

```
HM = [['', '', '', '', ''],
      ['', '', '', '', ''],
      ['', '', '', '', ''],
      ['', '', '', '', ''],
      ['', '', '', '', ''],
      ['', '', '', '', ''],
      ['', '', '', '', '']]
```

You can insert the sub-matrix in this way, for example:

```
B = [["AA", "BB"],["CC","DD"]]
offset = (1,2)

for x, row in enumerate(B):
  for y, e in enumerate(row):
    HM[x + offset[0]][y + offset[1]] = e

for row in HM:
  print(row)

# ['', '', '', '', '']
# ['', '', 'AA', 'BB', '']
# ['', '', 'CC', 'DD', '']
# ['', '', '', '', '']
# ['', '', '', '', '']
# ['', '', '', '', '']
# ['', '', '', '', '']
```

Comment: thx - Here I dont get your result - I do get [['', '', 'CC', 'DD', '', '', '', '', ''], ['', '', 'CC', 'DD', '', '', '', '', ''], ['', '', 'CC', 'DD', '', '', '', '', ''], ['', '', 'CC', 'DD', '', '', '', '', ''], ['', '', 'CC', 'DD', '', '', '', '', ''], ['', '', 'CC', 'DD', '', '', '', '', ''], ['', '', 'CC', 'DD', '', '', '', '', ''], ['', '', 'CC', 'DD', '', '', '', '', ''], ['', '', 'CC', 'DD', '', '', '', '', ''], ['', '', 'CC', 'DD', '', '', '', '', '']] - you have any idea why - and same effect as @yatu - - may be a bug ? I do get the same in P3.7 and P3.5.

Comment: @Erich, I can not give an explanation for that, in each line you end up with 9 elements. I got correct result either with Python 3.7 and  2.7. I edited adding the starting matrix.

Answer (score 0):

I failed to solve the issue using larger matrices (using 20x20 and 5x6 matrices) as in the first statement . I ended up using 3 matrix - an additional np.array to switch the access between the first two. All other solutions did not work  - imho there is a serious bug which should be solved, but this would show some "research effort" ...